# ajax post success parse json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

sorry for the long question. I am trying to ajax post to collect a contacts position history and then add the markers to the map.

The ajax post returns the positions data json encoded like:

```
[{"name":"Chris","data":{"user":"447967048843","data":[{"timestamp":1332840872,"longitude":-1.549517,"latitude":53.973174},{"timestamp":1332841510,"longitude":-1.444133,"latitude":53.997148}]},"contacts":null},{"name":"Jason","data":{"user":"447879896697","data":[{"timestamp":1332839836,"longitude":-1.566667,"latitude":53.978533},{"timestamp":1332840447,"longitude":-1.567654,"latitude":53.977927}]},"contacts":null}]
```

Here is the getHistory function which is called on form submit after the contact has been selected.

```
function getHistory() {
    var contact = $("#contact").val()
    var days = $("#days").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'temp_history.php',
        data: {contact: contact, days: days},
        context: document.body,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(succ){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(succ);
            var divs="",tabs="",counts=0;
            jQuery("#gMap").gmap3({
                action: 'clear'});
                jQuery(".marker").remove();
                jQuery.each(obj,function(i,item){
                tabs +=item.contacts;
                if(item.data.latitude != null && item.data.longitude!=null)
                    {
                    addMarker(item.name, item.data.timestamp,item.data.latitude,item.data.longitude,item.data.user_id);
                    }
            });
        }
  });
```

}

I think the problem is i need to nest the jQuery.each function but not sure how?

The addMarker function is:

```
 function addMarker(name, timestamp, lati, longi, user_id) {
    jQuery("#gMap").gmap3({
        action: 'addMarkers',
        markers:[
        {lat:lati, lng:longi, data:name}
        ]
    });
```

}

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in Firebug?

Comment: what doesn't work? have you checked for warnings/errors in firebug?

Comment: no errors, but also no markers.. It looks like the json data is multi dimensional array so i need to update function to suit, any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - your traversal of your JSON was incorrect, try this in your `success` handler:

```
success: function(data){
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // If you're returing json, this shouldn't be required
    var divs = "", tabs = "", counts = 0;

    jQuery("#gMap").gmap3({ action: 'clear' });
    jQuery(".marker").remove();

    jQuery.each(json, function(i, item) {
        var name = item.name;
        var userId = item.data.user;
        jQuery.each(item.data.data, function(i, nav) {
            var ts = nav.timestamp;
            var lat = nav.latitude;
            var long = nav.longitude;

            if (lat != null && long != null) {
                addMarker(name, ts, lat, long, userId);
            }
        });
    })  
}
```

Also, it would be worth making the object names in your JSON more semantic, especially as you have `data` listed in multiple levels.